# Is there any iphone call history downloader for windows which actually works?

Tags: iphone, windows, logs, call, history

Does anyone know an app (or procedure) that WORKs, to export the 4 months of iphone call logs, that everyone has been saying since 2016, is saved in iCloud?

Google is jammed with pages which say they "download call history for free", but DONT even *find ANY* (on phone, itunes or iCloud), as at April 2020.  They all look strangely similar, they all have "free download" buttons and then they don't work

(not 1 trial actually shows it properly finds and downloads all call history, several dont find even notes or reminders, others show wrong numbers of contacts...)

and then demand payment for their buggy software!

1. Minitool free $60 (CALL HISTORY EMPTY, ONLY ONE NOTE, 2 REMINDERS, double contacts, no whatsapp atts)
2. freeiphonerocovery gihosoft $60 (took hours, found 411 but cant view or download)
3. imanager gihosoft $35 only found 190
4. wondershare Dr Fone $99
5. Syncios $40, no call logs or whatsapp found, NW ios 9+
6. Easus MOBISAVER FREE $60- 0 call history, reminders, whatsapp; Mobimover doesnt even have button for call history
7. Tenorshare ultdata- $70,says found 1031, but doesn't show what dates it has recovered - and large patches of details missing completely - why would it hide PREVIEW if the app worked?
8. Imobie phonerescue

Copytrans doesn't (but doesn't say it can!)

Will post more apps- after I get rid of the migraine...

Comment: https://support.apple.com/HT208502

Comment: @ankii This makes a good answer actually. And it's even free :)

Comment: @ankii thank you!  Takes 7 days! at [https://privacy.apple.com/], under "other data".  The information about it is at [https://appleid.cdn-apple.com/access/guides/other-data/Call%20History%20-%20Guide_9b99582c9c35eba992f15ec0e1c03386.pdf?accessKey=1586768141_d97b00f6e2d87e2c575865b6aefacf67e4d5c57f55641d789bcc6382ec574624_%2Faccess_PDJ5ayGPQNLJZYZSHl5%2BrifSaA18LiftCk%2FZGx5Dmb9MrNSzIzXRf17xlGlGeSCw7nu2FP5Zxm3LrTD4Ts7LRlTNVqN%2BUQ%2FmO0KAd0GLarH40ecGRlc4s9hZ3Z0GPu37] reached from [https://privacy.apple.com/file-guides]

Please post your comment as an answer and I will mark it as such.

Comment: @nohillside see the number of times the poster was me :p https://apple.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=privacy.apple.com

Comment: !!!@x$%! Email from Icloud "Your data request has been cancelled for security reasons" - tells me to ask again - when I go to ask again my ACCOUNT IS LOCKED!!!  On the phone to support now, what is going on? (They've put loud discordant music on after I pressed the option for no music).  Waiting for "advanced" technical support

Answer (score 2):

- https://privacy.apple.com

Sign in and download the "other data" category.

> - Why does Apple store my call history?
>
> When you’re signed in to iCloud with your Apple ID on multiple devices, your call history is stored and synced to allow you to return calls from any of your devices. Apple doesn’t access or use this information for any other purpose. You can turn off this feature by turning off iCloud Drive in iCloud settings.

https://support.apple.com/HT208502

This page maintains the personal data downloads of an Apple ID. Whatever is ever recorded or synced with Apple servers can be requested after sign in, the download link is sent to Apple ID email. Account deactivation and deletion is also possible here.

There are some exceptions:

- End to End encrypted data, like iMessages.
- Items like books, music that you purchased, but you don't own.

Comment: This answer should have been correct.  The download page says it includes call history. But the downloaded data did not include call history. WTF

Comment: I answered thinking it helps you. Also, it was untested. I'll delete it tomorrow & you should contact apple support.

Comment: leave your answer here - hopefully EVERYONE who looks for this will contact apple support and get it fixed!!!  Thanks for what should be the right answer!