# Is there a way to automatically backup my iPhone call history to a csv or otherwise

Tags: iphone, backup

Is there a way to automatically backup my iPhone call history to a csv etc, and that this file will also stay on my iPhone or maybe be transferred into the cloud. There are many Mac apps that can do call history backups, but all of them (1) require me to connect my phone to the computer, (2) make an iTunes backup of my *entire iPhone* to my computer first before I can extract my calls (my Mac does not have enough space, I need 250GB for my iPhone backup which is literally my entire Mac SSD! And this process I so slow!) (3) require me to manually make the backup (I need an automatic solution). I am hoping to avoid these.

Btw the iPhone in question is an iPhone 6, with iOS 12.5.5.

Comment: Apps don't have access to the call history (for privacy reasons). Did you check whether https://imazing.com/ also works remotely (without access to a backup)?

Comment: Also, did you try to run a local backup with iTunes/Finder? I doubt it will require 250 GB, a lot of stuff doesn't actually get backed up at all (for various reasons).

Comment: every time I backup using iTunes, I don't have space ;(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any iphone call history downloader for windows which actually works?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/388179/is-there-any-iphone-call-history-downloader-for-windows-which-actually-works)

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at [PhoneView by Ecamm](https://www.ecamm.com/mac/phoneview/). I use to use it to access an iOS device to retrieve information.

As mentioned above, [iMazing](https://imazing.com) is also a useful product as well.